# Video time stamp calculation for 29.97

Tags: ms-media-foundation

I want to write a H264 video stream using the IMFSinkWriter from the Media Foundation. Everything is working as expected besides the frame rate. The frame rate is shown in the MediaInfo tool with:

```
Frame rate mode: Constant
Frame rate: 29.970 (29970/1000) FPS
Original frame rate: 29.970 (30000/1001) FPS
```

How can I achieve that my video stream will have a frame rate of 29.970 (30000/1001) FPS instead of 29.970 (29970/1000)?

```
//in a loop
IMFSample* imfSample = getSample(); 

static constexpr int64_t k100NanoSec = 10000000;
int64_t time = k100NanoSec * sampleNum * 1001 / 300000;
int64_t nextTime = k100NanoSec * (sampleNum + 1) * 1001 / 300000;
int64_t duration = nextTime - time;

imfSample->SetSampleDuration(duration); 
imfSample->SetSampleTime(time); 

sampleNum++;
```

The IMFMediaType for the input and output is:

```
IMFMediaType* mediaType = nullptr;
MFCreateMediaType (&mediaType);
mediaType->SetGUID (MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video);
mediaType->SetGUID (MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFVideoFormat_H264);
mediaType->SetUINT32 (MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE, 12200000);
MFSetAttributeSize (mediaType, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, 1920, 1080);
MFSetAttributeRatio (mediaType, MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, 30000, 1001);
MFSetAttributeRatio (mediaType, MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO, 1, 1);
mediaType->SetUINT32 (MF_MT_MPEG2_PROFILE, eAVEncH264VProfile_Base);

DWORD index;
writer->AddStream (mediaType, &index);
writer->SetInputMediaType (index, mediaType, nullptr);
```

I double check all return values - I have just removed the code here. The index value is 0.

Comment: So what is media type exactly (esp. `MF_MT_FRAME_RATE`) in `IMFSinkWriter::AddStream` call. Your attempt with 30000/1001 looks about right but the code snippet at the bottom of the question is not a proof that it's in its place.

Comment: @RomanR. I`ve updated my question with the complete media type. I use the same media type for the input and the output type of the sink writer.

Comment: If you use those values, what's the result : duration = 33366; time += duration; the duration is fixed and the time increases with the duration for each sample

Comment: To be honest the description of the problem does not even suggest that something is wrong. Multiplexers are free to choose numerator/denominator pairs for description atoms. Media type is about right, so maybe you can also attach a sample file as well.

Comment: On Windows7, the media type is not working... SetInputMediaType returns MF_E_INVALIDMEDIATYPE... On Windows8 and Windows10 the setup for the IMFSinkWriter is working...

Comment: That is very strange: if I change the media input subtype to MFVideoFormat_RGB32 - I can setup the IMFSinkWriter as expected. The IMFSinkWriter dll is "mfreadwrite.dll". Do you know this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it's the same.

I dowload a video mp4 file with 29.970 FPS (under "MP4 Sample Videos", download jellyfish-25-mbps-hd-hevc) :

[big-list-of-sample-videos-for-testers](https://standaloneinstaller.com/blog/big-list-of-sample-videos-for-testers-124.html)

I use MediaFoundation to check this file with a SourceReader and MFGetAttributeRatio on the video media type. I get 30000/1001.

Then i use MediaInfo with this file, and i get 29970/1000.

So i think it's just the way where MediaInfo decides to show the frame rate like this.

MediaInfo source code is available, so it's possible to verify this fact.

**PS** : I would like to thank you for this question. I was doing wrong calculation in my project H264Dxva2Decoder :

Before : llDuration = itTime->dwOffset * (10000000 / dwTimeScale);

After : llDuration = (LONGLONG)((itTime->dwOffset / (double)dwTimeScale) * 10000000);

Before : result was 333600

After : result is 333667 (using MFAverageTimePerFrameToFrameRate, get 30000 / 1001)